# Android Studio IDE Fatal Error - "Exception in plugin Gradle."

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio, gradle

I installed android studio first and After installed IDEA Intellij 13 and start developing on Intellij IDEA 13 and everything was ok.
(I set both programs SDK on one SDK package).
To day I want to switch back to Android Studio, But when click on "Project Structure" Button, I got below error.

```
Multiple entries with same key: 8=API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo) and 8=API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo): Multiple entries with same key: 8=API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo) and 8=API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: 8=API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo) and 8=API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.checkNoConflict(ImmutableMap.java:150)
    at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableBiMap.<init>(RegularImmutableBiMap.java:77)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap$Builder.build(ImmutableBiMap.java:172)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.KeyValuePane.<init>(KeyValuePane.java:138)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.AndroidProjectConfigurable.<init>(AndroidProjectConfigurable.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.<init>(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.DecoratingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(DecoratingComponentAdapter.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.CachingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingComponentAdapter.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.initializeInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:159)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter$1.compute(ServiceManagerImpl.java:147)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:921)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:139)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:225)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:199)
    at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.getComponentInstance(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:40)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.getInstance(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:112)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.actionPerformed(AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:313)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Please help me. thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete my android studio and its SDK and install again and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Android SDK Manager (standalone version) and check Android 2.2 section. If there are duplicate packages delete all except one with the latest revision number.