# Stacktrace.txt error in installing android studio

Tags: android-studio

I just installed Android Studio on my laptop and it shows an error stating ide fatal error. How can i fix this? Anyone who faces the same problem as mine?

Answer (score 0):

An error code or picture of the error would help but my first suggestion would always be to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio.

Possible Duplicate:
[Android Studio IDE Fatal Error - "Exception in plugin Gradle."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122979/android-studio-ide-fatal-error-exception-in-plugin-gradle)